# Refreshing output text in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I need to create kind of a monitor which refreshes itself periodically. So how can I properly refresh output of a cell? When I refresh the text using the code below the output pane collapses when being cleared creating annoying screen jumps.

```
from IPython import display
import time
while True:
    o = !netstat
    display.clear_output()
    display.publish_display_data({"text/plain":o.n})
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Best avatar ever.